# Tensorflow: how to create a 1D tensor of 0's and 1's given the indices of the 1's

Tags: python, tensorflow

As an example tensor of length 5, and the indices are 1, 3, and 4. The resulting tensor should be:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
a = []

indices = [1, 3, 4]
for i in range(5):
    if i in indices:
        a.append(1)
    else:
        a.append(0)


arr = numpy.array(a)

x = tf.convert_to_tensor(a, dtype=tf.float32)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(x))
```

Output:

```
[0. 1. 0. 1. 1.]
```

You can tweak the parameters of the indices and size of the array if you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use sparse tensor

```
import tensorflow as tf
sparse_tensor = tf.SparseTensor(
  dense_shape=[5],
  values=[1, 1, 1],
  indices =[[1],[3],[4]])
tensor = tf.sparse.to_dense(sparse_tensor)
print(tensor)
```